# Visual Studio error: /W needs an argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I get the title's error (said to be in file "cl" line 1) but I got no idea of the meaning...

I imported the projet via the .pro file (I need to use visual studio and Qt, because I'm using CONDITION_VARIABLE and Qt only allows his own QWaitCondition. and using QWaitCondition is not an option for me).

Comment: `cl` is the name of the compiler executable.

Comment: So why does VS tell me there's an error at line 1 ?

Comment: `-W` enables extra warnings in other compilers (e.g. GCC) and VS is happy to translate `-` into `/` so you probably imported some options for a different compiler.

Comment: There were /W3 and -W that were translated into /W, right answer

Comment: I don't know, maybe there's a script that invokes it on line 1. It's hard for me to say.

Answer (score 0):

The option `/W` is used to select a warning level for the compiler. But you also have to specify [*which* level you want](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx).

Comment: But it's written that I am in lvl3 warning level